# Pass selected index from ComboBox as converter parameter in XAML databinding

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

My XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind local:Amount, Converter={StaticResource VolumeConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_Amount_Unit" />
```

How can I pass the selected index of ComboBox_Amount_Unit as a parameter to the converter of the TextBox?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Shakir Ahmed for the time you took to help me with a solution. I just found a solution myself a couple of hours ago:

```
private double _BrewAmount = 10;
public double BrewAmount
{
    get { return _BrewAmount; }
    set
    {
        CorrectedBrewAmount = value.ToString();
    }
} // In database. Holds the volume in liters, no matter the ComboBox unit selection.

private string _CorrectedBrewAmount = "0";
public string CorrectedBrewAmount
{
    get
    {
        string[] Result = Convert.VolumeFromLiterWithUnitConversion(BrewAmount, BrewAmountSelectedIndex == -1 ? AppSettings.MeasuringSystem == MeasuringSystem.Systems[MeasuringSystem.Metric] ? LiquidUnit.Liter : LiquidUnit.Gallon : BrewAmountSelectedIndex);
        _CorrectedBrewAmount = Result[0];
        return Result[0];
    }
    set
    {
        _BrewAmount = Convert.VolumeToLiter(System.Convert.ToDouble(value), BrewAmountSelectedIndex == -1 ? AppSettings.MeasuringSystem == MeasuringSystem.Systems[MeasuringSystem.Metric] ? LiquidUnit.Liter : LiquidUnit.Gallon : BrewAmountSelectedIndex);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CorrectedBrewAmount");
    }
}   // Not in database. The value shown in the TextBox.

private int _BrewAmountSelectedIndex = -1;
public int BrewAmountSelectedIndex
{
    get { return _BrewAmountSelectedIndex; }
    set
    {
        _BrewAmountSelectedIndex = value;
        _BrewAmount = Convert.VolumeToLiter(System.Convert.ToDouble(_CorrectedBrewAmount), value == -1 ? LiquidUnit.Liter : value);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("BrewAmountSelectedIndex");
    }
} // Not in database. The bindable selected index.
```

I have some converters as functions and make use of a corrected property which is shown and bound in the UI, while the 'real' value is in the original property. It looks complicated, but it works like it should. You can see that the CorrectedBrewAmount and the BrewAmountSelectedindex are setting _BrewAmount so that the setter of BrewAmount (without the underscore) won't trigger. And when BrewAmount is set from code, then CorrectedBrewAmount is set which triggers the conversion.

Comment: Good. Are you using converter parameter in this solution? Just curious to know.

Comment: No, completely without a binding converter.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you (not tested):

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextbox"  Text="{x:Bind local:Amount, Converter={StaticResource VolumeConverter},ConverterParameter={Binding ElementName=ComboBox_Amount_Unit,Path=SelectedIndex}, Mode=TwoWay />
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_Amount_Unit" }" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't work. I keep getting null as parameter. I also tried without the path, to get the ComboBox or just use ontly Path=ComboBox_Amount_Unit.

Comment: Wait for a while. Let me see!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to accomplish ur goal:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App12.BlankPage2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App12"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:VolumeConverter x:Key="cvt"/>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox PlaceholderText="Input value in meter" 
                     Width="300" 
                     Text="{x:Bind InputValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Button Content="Calculate" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_Amount_Unit" 
                      Margin="0,30,0,0" 
                      Loaded="ComboBox_Amount_Unit_Loaded">
                <ComboBox.Items>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="mm"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="cm"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="M"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="kM"/>
                </ComboBox.Items>
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBlock Name="outputTextBlock" 
                       FontSize="25" 
                       Text="{x:Bind Volume, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource cvt}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>



    public sealed partial class BlankPage2 : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public static BlankPage2 Current;

            public BlankPage2()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();
                Current = this;
            }



            double _volume; 

            int _inputValue;

            public double Volume
            {
                get { return _volume; }
                set { _volume = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
            }

            public int InputValue
            {
                get { return _inputValue; }
                set { _inputValue = value; }
            }

            public int getIndex()
            {
                return ComboBox_Amount_Unit.SelectedIndex;
            }


            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = null)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
                }
            }

            private void ComboBox_Amount_Unit_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    Volume = InputValue * 1000000000;
                }
                else if ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    Volume = InputValue * 1000000;
                }
                else if ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    Volume = InputValue;
                }
                else if ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex == 3)
                {
                    Volume = InputValue / 1000000000;
                }
                else Volume = InputValue;
            }

            private void ComboBox_Amount_Unit_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                ComboBox_Amount_Unit.SelectedIndex = 0;
                ComboBox_Amount_Unit.SelectionChanged += ComboBox_Amount_Unit_SelectionChanged;
            }

            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (ComboBox_Amount_Unit.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    Volume = InputValue * 1000000000;
                }
                else if (ComboBox_Amount_Unit.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    Volume = InputValue * 1000000;
                }
                else if (ComboBox_Amount_Unit.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    Volume = InputValue;
                }
                else if (ComboBox_Amount_Unit.SelectedIndex == 3)
                {
                    Volume = InputValue / 1000000000;
                }
                else Volume = InputValue;
            }
        }


    public class VolumeConverter: IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
            {
                double val = (double)value;

                if (val == 0.0) return "";

                int index = BlankPage2.Current.getIndex();

                if(index == 0)
                {
                    return val.ToString() + " " + "mm";
                }
                else if(index == 1)
                {
                    return val.ToString() + " " + "cm";
                }
                else if(index == 2)
                {
                    return val.ToString() + " " + "m";
                }
                else if (index == 3)
                {
                    return val.ToString() + " " + "km";
                }

                return val.ToString();
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```